# Update max_page on jqPagination jquery plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

i want to update the max_page to a value that i receive from an ajax call.
how can i do that?
thanks.

```
$('.pagination').jqPagination({
        max_page: $pages, // variable that i set on an ajax call
        paged: function (page) {
            $("#content").fadeIn(500, function () {
                    list($user, (page - 1) * 5);
            });
        }
    });
```

Comment: Do you get any JavaScript errors when you do this? So long as `$pages` is a number this should work. Better yet, have you got an example?

Comment: Actually, you're saying to want to "update" the `max_page` value, do you mean updated after jqPaginaiton has already been instantiated?

Answer (score 0):

I update a hidden field (maxPage) using the ajax call and then use the hidden value to update the max_page;

```
$('.pagination').jqPagination({
    max_page: $('#maxPage').val(), // hidden field that I update with ajax call
    paged: function (page) {
        $("#content").fadeIn(500, function () {
                list($user, (page - 1) * 5);
        });
    }
});
```